# Creating a python set/unique list

Tags: python, list, set, immutability, anagram

I'm trying to get a unique list using set but my looping method shows all the possibilities and repeats some of the list member already present - it just swaps them around. I am thinking maybe I should use a dictionary - just make one member constant and avoid doing the current looping method.

Tried:

```
a=['hello','mam','dictionary','why','lives','elvis','hey','indicatory']
x = 1
while x < len(a):
    for i in a:
        if signature(a[x]) == signature(i) and a[x] != i:
            anagram=print([a[x],i],end =' ')
    x += 1

print(set(anagram))
```

Got an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Code I am having problems with:

```
def signature(word):
    return ''.join(sorted(word))

a=['hello','mam','dictionary','why','lives','elvis','hey','indicatory']

x = 1
unique_list = []
while x < 8:
    for i in a:
        if signature(a[x]) == signature(i) and a[x] != i:
            y = (a[x], i)
            unique_list.append(y)                                            
    x += 1

print(list(set(unique_list)))
```

Actual result:
    [('lives', 'elvis'), ('elvis', 'lives'), ('indicatory', 'dictionary'), ('dictionary', 'indicatory')]

Expected result:
    [('lives', 'elvis'), ('indicatory', 'dictionary')]

Comment: You are correct that a dictionary is a natural choice. You can create a list whose keys are signatures and whose values are lists of words.

Comment: Elements of list a are enumerated form 0 to len(a)-1. So when your index x reaches len(a) (8) it generates "list index out of range" error.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). You can then do

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
a = ['hello','mam','dictionary','why','lives','elvis','hey','indicatory']
for i in a:
    d[''.join(sorted(i))].append(i)
out = [tuple(i) for i in d.values() if len(i) > 1]
print(out)
```

prints

```
[('dictionary', 'indicatory'), ('lives', 'elvis')]
```

Comment: This is the most *Python*ic one. I was going to add a similar version to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
a=['hello','mam','dictionary','why','lives','elvis','hey','indicatory']
anagrams = set([])
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
        if sorted(a[i]) == sorted(a[j]):
            anagrams.add((a[i], a[j]))
print(anagrams)
```

Comment: Or you can print the list like `print(list(anagrams))` to get your expected result

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you seem to have two loops trying to do the same thing? It's confusing.
Second, you could sort each of your tuples and then make a set, converting between string and tuple all the while, but the simpler solution is this:

```
x = 0
unique_list = []
while x < len(a):
    for i in a[x + 1:]:
        if signature(a[x]) == signature(i):
            unique_list.append((a[x], i))
    x += 1
print(unique_list)
```

Here, `a[x + 1:]` is a slice taking only the words in the list that are *after* the word we're currently checking. By construction, there can be no duplicates, you save time on the `a[x] != i` check, and you do fewer iterations.

The `while` loop is a tad unconventional given that we're only reading from the list `a`, the more standard way would be `for x in range(len(a)):`, but do as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I addressed the case sensitivity as well.

```
b=set()
for x in a:
   i = 0
   i = i + 1
   for y in a[i:]:
      if len(x) == len(y):
          if "".join(sorted(x.lower())) == "".join(sorted(y.lower())):
              if x != y:
                  b.add(tuple((sorted((x,y)))))
 print b
```

Comment: There are no guidelines that not to put the screenshots over here and also giving -2 is like kind of discouragement.. Anyway i have updated the answer with code.

Comment: See [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/4996248) regarding screenshots. In this case, the purpose of the downvote was to encourage you to edit, not discourage you to answer. I removed the downvote, but your code is a bit odd. Why the two lines whose sole effect is to set `i = 1`? The variable `i` is not modified in the loop, and doesn't really make sense. Are you sure that you want the initialization `i = 0` to be in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

For each word in the list only check the words that comes after it. That way you won't have "reversed duplicates". 
Below it's a modified (and improved) version of your code (that also uses [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Functions - **enumerate**(*iterable, start=0)*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), to keep track of both current index and current element during iteration).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def signature(word):
    return sorted(word)


def anagrams(word_list):
    result = list()
    for index0, word0 in enumerate(word_list):
        for _, word1 in enumerate(word_list[index0 + 1:]):  # Slice starting from the word that comes AFTER word0
            if signature(word0) == signature(word1):
                result.append((word0, word1))
    return result


def main():
    words = ["hello", "mam", "dictionary", "why", "lives", "elvis", "hey", "indicatory"]
    print(anagrams(words))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057686401]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> [('dictionary', 'indicatory'), ('lives', 'elvis')]
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use following code to get a unique list.

```
    list = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] not in list:
            list.append(a[i])
    print(list)
```